# Linux/bash environment variable is null when reading from java

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, bash

In Ubuntu I have exported the below environment variable in **~/.bashrc**:

```
export MY_VAR="MY_VAR_VALUE"
```

When I re-open a terminal I can do:

```
~ $ echo $MY_VAR
MY_VAR_VALUE
~ $
```

But when I do this in Java/Eclipse (which I have restarted after exporting the test env. var):

```
String myVar = System.getenv("MY_VAR");
System.out.println(myVar);
```

I just get **null**. Does eclipse not see variables set in ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: Depends on how you start Eclipse. Is it running from a script or console that has your Bash environment set? Try running the Java program directly from a Bash prompt.

Comment: it doesn't see variables set in ~/.bashrc. You must pass by the shell or create a script which export  variables and launch eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux (unlike Windows) you need a direct child relatinship between the Java executable, started by Eclipse, started by the Shell where you have exported the variable.

So you must start Eclipse from within that Shell. It wont work if you doubleclick on the executable in desktop or menu.

But I would specify the environment variables you need in the run configuration and not rely on such a setup.